# How to wrap FCE container with link?

Tags: typo3

I have an FCE (Flexible Content Element) that has a container ROOT as usual and I want to wrap it with a link from a "link field" inside the FCE.

The issue is that the "Container for Elements" data structure doesn't have the field "Custom stdWrap" so I'm not able to easily add `typolink.parameter.field = field_link`.

So how can I wrap the main div (mapped by Container for Elements) in a `<a href>|</a>` using as link one of the link fields inside the FCE?

And I'd like to integrate this in the FCE itself not adding external typoscript.

Image of the templatevoila mapping. I wish to wrap the container ROOT with a `<a href></a>` using as link the URL element's value.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code? Can you change the default typoscript?

Comment: I'm doing the mapping with templavoila so there isn't any code "per say"...at least I don't think there is

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot link the root element of a FCE** There are a couple of workarounds.

First you could define a **MAPPED** link, that creates a **a tag** in html inside the fce. Stretch the a tag so that it matches the dimensions of the wrapping root. This is a pure css solution. The a tag has to be positioned within its container absolutely to acomplish this.

For the other solution you need **TWO** FCE. One containing the link and an content element. The field you mapped as content element will hold your second fce with background image, text and caption.

Comment: I think I didn't understand what you meant. If I wanted to link a simple image to the url field I could simply do 'typolink.parameter.field = field_link'. The issue is I don't have an image element nor an element (besides the root container) that wraps all the other elements and I want to make the FCE linked to a specific URL. In fact, if I understood your solution correctly I wouldn't even need the hidden element you added....I could set the link field just "NOT MAPPED"

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but I can't do that either...I'm using a javascript slider which has several of the FCE shown in the image wrapped in a main container...meaning that each one of these FCE has its own url and not one for all. Can't I somehow wrap each FCE in a custom link using a template typoscrip stdWrap?